# php prepared statements: unique username and email error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

How can I create unique usernames and unique emails with prepared statements? I know the code that I have is wrong because, as of now, the correct error message will display if I enter an already taken username but the error message will also show for the email even if it is unique (and vice versa).

Any idea on how to fix this?

```
 else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=? OR user_email=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?sqlerror");
            exit();
        }

        else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $name, $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        array_push($error_array, "taken.<br>");
        }
```

Comment: Please edit in additional details instead of reposting.

Comment: So you want error messages like "email taken" or "username taken" right?

Comment: @Pilan yes, that's correct. I would want both to show up if needed, but as of now I only how to implement one of the error messages

Comment: Make those (2) DATABASE columns UNIQUE, so that when one registers, the username and the email are unique system wide. That will stop you from having to needlessly CHECK if they already exist as an ERROR will be thrown when you try to INSERT a new USER, or any registered user from trying to register a new USER with a email that has already been used to create a existing account...

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (user_name);
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (user_email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. If you want to have 2 cases, you have to ask twice :)

```
$stmt->bind_result($db_name, $db_email);
$stmt->fetch();

if($db_name == $name) {
    array_push($error_array, "name taken.<br>");
}

if($db_email == $email) {
    array_push($error_array, "email taken.<br>");
}
```

Comment: I think I may be implementing this method wrong. I tried it a couple ways and it doesn't seem to be working. Where would I insert the suggested code?

Comment: Why do things that make no sense at all... when a database has the means to keep you the developer from doing things that are defy any type of sound logic!

Comment: just replace your `if($resultCheck...) {... }` with it. The 2 lines above it aswell.
Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) for additional infos.

Comment: I tried this but it hasn't worked for me. It ignores the errors and allows the user to sign up with an existing or already registered username or email.

Comment: Yes, this code just pushes error-messages to an array. If you want to prevent the insert you have wrap your insert in something like this: `if(count($error_array) === 0) { /* do insert */ } else { /* display errors*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I mean, if you simply alter those (2) database columns....

```
<?php

$_POST['user_name'] = 'admin'; // should be cleaned and validated

$_POST['user_email'] = 'test@gmail.com'; // should be cleaned and validated

/* open a connection */

$con = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'login_user', 'login_pass', 'database' );

/* check the connection */

if ( mysqli_connect_errno ( ) )
{
    echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error () . "\r\n\r\n";

    exit ( );
}

/* initialize the statement */

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init ( $con );

/* the query / sql statement */

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email) VALUES (?,?);";

/* test the sql statement */

if ( mysqli_stmt_prepare ( $stmt, $sql ) === TRUE )
{
    /* bind the param(s) to the sql statement */

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( $stmt, "ss", $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_email'] );

    /* try to execute the sql statement */

    if ( mysqli_stmt_execute ( $stmt ) === FALSE )
    {
        /* show developer error, duplicate found, this would not be here */

        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error ( $con ) . "\r\n\r\n";


        /* show the user error, duplicate found */

        echo "Error: the username and or password already exist on are system\r\n";

        exit ( );   
    }
    else
    {
        /* close the sql statement */

        mysqli_stmt_close ( $stmt );

        echo "New User Added\r\n\r\n";

        exit ( );
    }

}
else /* query, sql statement error */
{
    echo "Query Error: " . mysqli_error ( $con ) . "\r\n\r\n";
}

/* close the connection */

mysqli_close ( $con );

?>
```